# Where is the oposite of imagecreatefromstring

Tags: php

I have an image in a string `$data`. I need to resize that image, so I convert it to a `image` with `imagecreatefromstring`. How to I get that resized image back to `$data` variable? All I've found is `imagepng` in its ilk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`imagepng`](http://www.php.net/imagepng) with [output buffering](http://www.php.net/book.outcontrol):

```
ob_start();
imagepng($image);
$data = ob_get_clean();
```

Comment: @Somebody: Probably, but why touch the disk when you don't have to?